# Append indices of element to each element

Tags: python, numpy

So basically I want to create a new array for each element and append the coordinates of the element to the original value (so adding the x and y position to the original element):

```
[ [7,2,4],[1,5,3] ]
```

then becomes

```
[ [[0,0,7][0,1,2][0,2,4]],
 [[1,0,1][1,1,5][1,2,3]] ]
```

I've been looking for different ways to make this work with the axis system in NumPy but I'm probably overseeing some more obvious way.

Comment: If your list objects are very large, you could reconsider whether this operation is really necessary, or whether you could access the indices on the fly in whatever operation you do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `np.meshgrid` to create a grid and then `np.stack` to combine it with input array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[7,2,4],[1,5,3]])
result = np.stack(np.meshgrid(range(a.shape[1]), range(a.shape[0]))[::-1] + [a], axis=-1)
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 7],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 2, 4]],

       [[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 5],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without numpy you could use list comprehension:

```
old_list = [ [7,2,4],[1,5,3] ]
new_list = [ [[i,j,old_list[i][j]] for j in range(len(old_list[i]))] for i in range(old_list) ]
```

I'd assume that numpy is faster but the sublists are not required to have equal length in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `enumerate`

```
In [38]: merge = list()
    ...: for i,j in enumerate(val):
    ...:     merge.append([[i, m, n] for m, n in enumerate(j)])
    ...:

In [39]: merge
Out[39]: [[[0, 0, 7], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4]], [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it useful

```
a = np.array([[7,2,4], [1,5,3]])
idx = np.argwhere(a)
idx = idx.reshape((*(a.shape), -1))
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=-1)
a = np.concatenate((idx, a), axis=-1)
```